# Why my session value changed for a particular value?

Tags: javascript, session, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-views

Can someone help understand why my session value changed for a particular value, 03375?

My MVC controller code:

```
Session["something"] = "03375";
```

My view js code:

```
$(function(){
 alert(@Session["something"].ToString()); 
});
```

Result: js alerts 1789. Why???

It works for other values except. Here is a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/zLdyO8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with asp.net session. If you do this in your page

```
console.log(03375);
```

You will get `1789`

**Why is this happening ?**

Because when browser's javascript runtime sees a number starting with `0` prefix, it thinks it is **octal** representation of the number. **In fact `03375` is the octal equivalent of `1789`**. So your browser is basically converting the octal value 
to it's decimal equivalent and giving you `1789` (*browsers usually parse the number to decimal representation*)

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates),

> Note that decimal literals can start with a zero (0) followed by
>   another decimal digit, but if every digit after the leading 0 is
>   smaller than 8, the number gets parsed as an octal number.

This means, if you are trying

```
console.log(09375);
```

It will print,`9375` !!!

To handle your case, the ideal solution is to set the correct type value. For example, if you are passing a numeric value, simply set the numeric value instead of the string version with leading zero..

```
Session["something"] = "3375";
```

Or even better

```
Session["something"] = 3375;
```

Then in the client side,

```
alert(@Session["something"]);
```

If you absolutely want to keep the `0` prefix, while setting the session value, but you want the value as number at client side, you can read it in a string and then use `parseInt` to convert it to a number type

```
var r = '@Session["something"].ToString()';
alert(r);  // the string with leading 0
var n = parseInt(r);
alert(n);  // the number
alert(typeof(n));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Learn something new today! Thanks again!